# How to provide model dependency information for use by Django's dumpdata?

Tags: django-models

Attempting to run the dumpdata command in Django release 1.2.1:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp
```

I get the error "Can't resolve dependencies for myapp.model1 myapp.model2 myapp.model3".

Dumpdata is fine if I specify the list of models - e.g.,

```
./manage dumpdata myapp.model1 myapp.model2 myapp.model3 etc.
```

Is there a way to encode the dependency information in my models.py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manage.py dumpdata command incorrectly interprets ManyToMany relationships as dependencies of the model that declares them (rather than the other way around). There is a open ticket for this problem:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14226

Try to apply the attached patch, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - turns out that's my ticket :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using natural_keys & MySQL? There's a bug reported on this.

Try commenting out all you natural_keys' code. Then dumpdata and voila.

Comment: A link to the bug report would make this answer better.